# How do I exclude a FOLDER from SourceTree version control client?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I want to exclude Expression Web 4's *vti* folders from version control
(Don't laugh at me using EW :)

is it just adding to the ignore list:

> /*vti**

FYI, I'm using Mercurial through Bit

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a `.hgignore` file (if you don't have one yet) in the root directory with these 2 lines

```
syntax: glob

vti*
```

should work.